# Number of faces of a polytopal subdivision

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-topology, polyhedra

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a (bounded) polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a *polytopal subdivision* of $\mathcal{P}$ [[1](http://books.google.de/books?id=xd25TXSSUcgC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q&f=false)].

Is there a known tight upper bound in the number of polytopes in $\mathcal{C}$   for $\sum_{P \in \mathcal{C}} f(P)$
where $f(P)$ denotes the *number of faces* of the polytope $P$?

*Note:* A trivial upper bound can be achieved by the dual version of the upper bound theorem [[2](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/soft/polyfaq/node12.html)].